# write output to a file dynamically in unix

Tags: shell, unix

i want the output of the script need to be write it into the file i.e QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh

here my script file **qr_script.sh**

```
dt=$(date "+%d/%B/%Y")
prev=$(date --date yesterday "+%d/%B/%Y")
fdt=$(date --date yesterday "+%d-%m-%Y")
echo "$fdt"
echo "Date :$prev"
grep -F "$prev" access_log|grep -F 'GET /?p='
echo "count :$(grep -F "$prev" access_log|grep -F 'GET /?p='|wc -l)"
cat >QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
 exec >>QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
```

I am not sure about last 2 lines.

my problem is when i run the script the file created but the output is not append to newly created file and script execution waits after creation of file when i write something that will be appends to the file but not the output generated by the script

what my newly created file must be like output of the **qr_script.sh**

that will be like this

```
Date :13/May/2014
183.82.99.35 - - [13/May/2014:03:03:16 -0400] "GET /?p=135873 HTTP/1.1" 301 281
183.82.99.35 - - [13/May/2014:03:03:49 -0400] "GET /?p=134201 HTTP/1.1" 301 281
183.82.99.35 - - [13/May/2014:03:04:06 -0400] "GET /?p=134201 HTTP/1.1" 301 281
183.82.99.35 - - [13/May/2014:03:04:25 -0400] "GET /?p=134201 HTTP/1.1" 301 281
count :4
```

if anybody have any idea about my problem.Help Me to resolve it
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could tell us what you are trying to achieve, what you expect the lines to do, and what you observe, that would be very useful to debug the problem.

Comment: @user3531971, what is the problem with above code?

Comment: HI,Thanq.i need create a file with name as QR_bar_code_14-05-2014.sh.the data of the file must be the output of the above code that must be done after i excute my file qr_script.sh

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski my problem is when i run the script the file created but the output is not append to newly created file and script execution waits after creation of file when i write something that will be appends to the file but not the output

Comment: Try `touch QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh` instead of `cat > QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh`. `cat` wants to read input so that it can copy it to its output... `touch` will just create the file. Alternatively, don't bother creating it - the first `something >> QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh` will create it if it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
prev=$(date --date yesterday "+%d/%B/%Y")
fdt=$(date --date yesterday "+%d-%m-%Y")
echo "$fdt" >QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
echo "Date :$prev" >>QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
grep -F "$prev" access_log|grep -F 'GET /?p=' >>QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
echo "count :$(grep -F "$prev" access_log|grep -F 'GET /?p='|wc -l)" >>QR_bar_code_$fdt.sh
```

Comment: Thanq @@Grzegorz Adam Kowalski.the data append to file but where should i write file create code, i write it before first echo statement then the script execution wait for data to write it into file when i press ctrl+d then the script executes and the output got what i really need.can u please help me to resolve this too.

Comment: @user3531971, I do not understand whay you're trying to achieve. Could you please explain in to me once again but using other words? Or maybe you can expand your original questions with more examples showing how all this is supposed to work.